# Definition of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, definition

Is this a valid definition? : A prime number can be constructed from other positive integers by addition, but not by multiplication.

(I am neither a math student nor a professional, but maths somehow got into my head recently. I am trying to understand things in terms which seem as simple as possible to me. Anything beyond quadratic equations rapidly leaves me in the dust. Calculus is way beyond my grasp for now.)

Edit : I guess I am trying to get a handle on the relationship between one and primes by sticking to the numberline and avoiding representing composites as 2d objects as they appear to me when they are a product.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Perhaps you mean constructed from *other* positive integers.  $3=1\times3$ is prime

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a valid definition unless you state precisely what you mean by "construct by addition/multiplication". The usual definition of a prime number is that it is a positive integer with exactly two (positive) factors. That doesn't require knowledge of calculus to understand, does it? :)

Comment: A prime number $p$ has only $1$ and itself as positive integer (*natural*) factors. For various good reasons, the natural number $1$ *is defined not to be prime*! To talk about construction, you should know that any *composite* number (non-prime), is *composable* - hence the name - as the product of two or more primes. This is called the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. For example, $24=3\times2\times2\times2$; this works for any positive integer, of any size, other than $1$, but I suppose $1$ is considered an "empty product".

Comment: A prime number can only be reached by numbers other than itself through addition, as you say, if you only consider addition and multiplication to be valid ways of "constructing", reaching, integers.

Comment: No. Prime numbers can be constructed by division of other numbers. For example, $3=18/6$. $11=1100/100$ etc.

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner. I didn't see the x1 issue, and the solution is so simple I didn't understand it for ages.

Comment: @Joe, I don't understand why I need to define "construct by addition/multiplication when the delightfully succinct definition you shared does not define factors. If I had used the terms sum/product would it sidestep the need for extra definitions?

Comment: @FShrike the attempt at a definition only mentions addition and multiplication, which I thought would suffice to exclude other operations.

Comment: @AdamRubinson. Can you explain how my attempt at a definition is inconsistent with the fact that integers can be constructed by division of integers? Is it somehow implicit that I'm talking about division without even mentioning it?

Comment: @Fshrike with regards to 1 being an "empty product" in terms of that theory, I consider 1 as the fundamental unit, and primes as secondary units. I guess I am trying to get a handle on the relationship between them by sticking to the numberline and avoiding representing composites as 2d objects as they appear to me when they are a product.

Comment: Well, you have your relation. Primes are "fundamental units" because they are "building blocks" for the whole integer number line; all integers are expressible as $1$ or $-1$ multiplied by some set of primes. All composite numbers are composed of two or more primes in this way

Comment: @ToMath: The term "factor" is standard mathematical terminology that will be familiar to the vast majority of my audience; this is not so with "construction by addition/multiplication". It's for the same reason that I didn't feel the need to define what "positive" meant when I was giving the definition.

Comment: Its a fail. However I churn it out, its just an inverted version of "a positive integer with exactly two (positive) factors" with unnecessary extra information about addition.

Comment: @Joe, if you post your first comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joe said in his comment, a prime number is a positive integer with exactly two distinct (positive integer) factors.